# Reshaping a column based on another column in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
Date          Sin      Ret
01/01/1990    True    0.03  
01/02/1990    True    0.02
01/01/1990    False   0.01  
01/02/1990    False   0.05
```

I would like

```
Date          Ret1    Ret2
01/01/1990    0.03    0.01
01/02/1990    0.02    0.05
```

so that I can get

```
Date          Ret1-Ret2
01/01/1990    0.02
01/02/1990    -0.03
```

What is the best way to do this? I was thinking setting Date and sin as index and unstack sin. Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think setting index and stacking is a good idea but here is an alternative with pivot:

```
(df.pivot(index='Date', columns='Sin', values='Ret')
   .rename(columns={True: 'Ret1', False: 'Ret2'}))

Sin         Ret1  Ret2
Date                  
01/01/1990  0.03  0.01
01/02/1990  0.02  0.05
```

Comment: can you give me a brief example where one is clearly better than the other? I have never had a use case where I wanted to use pivot (which can't be done by stack), so don't really know else what it does.

Comment: To get your output, you could do: `df.pivot(index='Date', columns='Sin', values='Ret').T.diff().iloc[-1]`

Comment: @Lost1 To be honest I don't think there is any difference. Source code of [pivot](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/reshape/reshape.py#L362) seem to suggest it is doing indexing/unstacking under the hood as well.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Yes, thanks. `diff` also accepts an axis argument so you can do `.diff(axis=1)` without transposing.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution with `df.set_index` and `df.unstack`:

```
In [516]: df.set_index(['Date', 'Sin']).unstack(0).diff().iloc[-1]
Out[516]: 
     Date      
Ret  01/01/1990    0.02
     01/02/1990   -0.03
Name: True, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Nice and succinct ~

Answer (score 1):

My solution only target the final output.

```
df.Sin=df.Sin.astype(int).replace({0:-1})
df.Ret=df.Sin.mul(df.Ret)
df.groupby('Date')['Ret'].agg({'Ret1-Ret2':'sum'})
            Ret1-Ret2
Date                 
01/01/1990       0.02
01/02/1990      -0.03
```